# Undeclared identifier in JwaWinCrypt

Tags: web-services, delphi, jedi

I am using JwaWinCrypt from
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/

for including certificate in web service, but when I try to access "PCCERT_CONTEXT" by using JwaWinCrypt.pas in my Form, it doesn't find PCCERT_CONTEXT or CERT_CONTEXT or any other values  for that matter. I don't know what am I doing wrong, considering everywhere I looked they just included that pas in "uses" and it worked. This is just driving me crazy because I cannot figure it out.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them declared in unit `Soap.Win.CertHelper` for XE2+.

Versions before that is in unit `CertHelper.pas`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's defined in JwaWinCrypt:

```
  PCERT_CONTEXT = ^CERT_CONTEXT;
  {$EXTERNALSYM CERT_CONTEXT}
  _CERT_CONTEXT = record
    dwCertEncodingType: DWORD;
    pbCertEncoded: LPBYTE;
    cbCertEncoded: DWORD;
    pCertInfo: PCERT_INFO;
    hCertStore: HCERTSTORE;
  end;
  {$EXTERNALSYM _CERT_CONTEXT}
  CERT_CONTEXT = _CERT_CONTEXT;
  {$EXTERNALSYM CERT_CONTEXT}
  TCertContext = CERT_CONTEXT;
  PCertContext = PCERT_CONTEXT;

  PCCERT_CONTEXT = PCERT_CONTEXT;
  {$EXTERNALSYM PCCERT_CONTEXT}
  PPCCERT_CONTEXT = ^PCCERT_CONTEXT;
  {$NODEFINE PCCERT_CONTEXT}
```

So PCCERT_CONTEXT and CERT_CONTEXT both exist (meaning you are likely making another error but I can't tell since you didn't share your code)